# What do Demon Seals look like and how do I destroy them?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm in Wonder City now, and the destructible items in this area are Demon Seals. After interrogating a Riddler Informant, I have the location of one of these items marked on my map. Unfortunately, there's no way to tell where the item is vertically, and I have no idea what I'm looking for. The specific location is in the Wonder Tower Foundations just below the center of where the walkways cross.

I thought it was this demon-like looking head above the Wonder City sign on the elevator shaft and below the two lights, but none of the weapons in my arsenal seem to affect it.

Am I looking at the wrong item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have pointy ears and yellow eyes. If you're in detective mode, you can see a hint of their eyes glowing. They also have a ring at the bottom.

[image: Found at nowgamer.com]

You want to use the batclaw on them and pull them off the wall.

Found the image on the [nowgamer.com guide](http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/arkham-city-cheats/1113408/batman_arkham_city_riddler_trophies_collectables_and_challenges_locations_guide.html), if you need a guide.